# How to use gcov with QMake for code coverage

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmake, gcov

I would like to use gcov with my unit test written using QTestLib.  I have managed to generate some .gcno files along my object files by adding this to my .pro file :

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -O0
```

But, when I run :

```
gcov main.cpp.gcno
```

I got a bunch of .gcov files generated with non-useful content (nothing like what I see in the tutorials on the web) :

```
-:    0:Source:main.cpp
-:    0:Graph:main.gcno
-:    0:Data:-
-:    0:Runs:0
-:    0:Programs:0
-:    1:/*EOF*/
-:    2:/*EOF*/
-:    3:/*EOF*/
-:    4:/*EOF*/
-:    5:/*EOF*/
-:    6:/*EOF*/
-:    7:/*EOF*/
-:    8:/*EOF*/
-:    9:/*EOF*/
-:   10:/*EOF*/
-:   11:/*EOF*/
-:   12:/*EOF*/
-:   13:/*EOF*/
-:   14:/*EOF*/
#####:   15:/*EOF*/
-:   16:/*EOF*/
#####:   17:/*EOF*/
-:   18:/*EOF*/
-:   19:/*EOF*/
#####:   20:/*EOF*/
-:   21:/*EOF*/
-:   22:/*EOF*/
-:   23:/*EOF*/
-:   24:/*EOF*/
#####:   25:/*EOF*/
#####:   26:/*EOF*/
-:   27:/*EOF*/
-:   28:/*EOF*/
-:   29:/*EOF*/
#####:   30:/*EOF*/
```

My source files are under *./MyProject/test/src* directory and all my object files are in a .obj directory underneath src (ie: *.MyProject/test/src/.obj*).  All binaries are created in *./MyProject/build* directory.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you run your QT program? Until then there's no coverage data.
Also, have a look at lcov, which you can use to get a nice html-based report of everything

Comment: You are right for the coverage data : there is data in the files now. Also, I have to provide gcov with the option -o .obj because my object files are in a separate directory from my source.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that instead of directly manipulating the CXX_FLAGS, qmake has (had for a while now) a gcov CONFIG option which seems to work more reliably:

I implemented it with this conditional in my .pro files:

```
isEmpty(RELEASE_BUILD) {
CONFIG += gcov
}
```